# How to make the scroll speed of background image of the webpage slower

Tags: css, html, parallax, vertical-scrolling

I  wanted to make a parallax effect but I try lots of ways still can't do it. now I have half of the parallax effect which is the background image are fixed, without moving and the next image will cover the previous image, but now I want it to become when I scrolling down the background image will move down too but just slower than the original speed.

[My code here](http://jsfiddle.net/6gcax9vq/1)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
html, body
{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%
}

html
{
 overflow:hidden;
}

body
{
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 perspective: 1px;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 overflow-x:hidden;
 overflow-y:scroll;
}


*
{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 font-family: Century Gothic;
}

.top
{
 background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.8),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url('../image/Kinkis-Bottomless-Brunch-Lead-Image.jpg');
 height: 100vh;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position:center;
 background-attachment:fixed;
}




.bottom
{
 background-image:url('../image/AdobeStock_80592193.jpeg');
 height: 100vh;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position:center;
 background-attachment:fixed;
}



.main{
 max-width: 1500px;
 margin: auto;
 margin-left:80px;
}


.main2{
 max-width: 1500px;
 margin: auto;
 margin-left:80px;
}



.nav
{
 float:left;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-top:55px;
 margin-left:65px;
}


.account
{
 font-size: 25px;
 font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}



ul li
{
 display: inline-block;
}



ul li a
{
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 5px 20px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 transition: 0.6s ease;

}


ul li a:hover
{
 background-color: #fff;
 color:#000;
}


ul li .active a
{
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #000;
  
}


.logo img
{
 float: left;
 width: 150px;
 height: auto;
 margin-top: 40px;
}



.title
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 45%;
 left: 34%;
 
}

.title h1
{
 color:#fff;
 font-size:70px;
 font-family: "Brush Script MT",Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


.title2
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 110%;
 left: 23%;
}

.title2 h2
{
 color: black;
 font-size:70px;
 font-family: "Brush Script MT",Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

</style>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="main">
        <div class="logo">
          <img alt="" src="TAO_LOGO1.jpg">
        </div>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="#">Gallary</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="account">Account</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="title">
          <h1>TAO Restaurant</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>




    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="main">
        <div class="title">
          <h1>TAO Restaurant</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: jsfiddle.net/6gcax9vq/1 this is my code

Comment: There is a very hacky way to create [parallax purely with css](https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) but other than that I would recommend you to use javascript for this. There are a lot of plugins if you don't have sufficient JS knowledge like [this one](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/).

Comment: I think even this could be very helpful [How TO - Parallax Scrolling](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp)

Comment: actually..I have try these code but its not working for me... it will cause either the background become scroll or keep fixed..

Comment: @Matt this just describes the effect which OP already has, though. It's also not really a parallax as it just "fixes" the position of the image, contrary to what OP wants (have them move **slower**, not **not at all**.)

Comment: sorry @Maharkus I thought it might be useful

Comment: I keep trying to use jquery or script from google but it not work for me.. maybe my code have problem or something I think..

Comment: @Matt its all good, I didn't mean to come off as condescending :)

Comment: I put together a simple parallax effect in the answers below. Let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a very simple example of a parallax effect using jQuery:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  $("img").css("top", "0" + (scroll / 1.8) + "px");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.block {
  background: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
  <div class="block">Some text</div>
</div>
```

and here the same approach is specifically applied to your case:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
 $("#header").css("background-position", "0%" + (scroll / -1.8) + "px");
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

html {
}

body {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Century Gothic;
}

.top {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('https://placeimg.com/640/640/any');
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.bottom {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.main {
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 80px;
}

.main2 {
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 80px;
}

.nav {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-left: 65px;
}

.account {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

ul li .active a {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.logo img {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 34%;
}

.title h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: "Brush Script MT", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.title2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 110%;
  left: 23%;
}

.title2 h2 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: "Brush Script MT", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header" class="top">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="logo">
      <img alt="" src="TAO_LOGO1.jpg">
    </div>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Gallary</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="account">Account</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="title">
      <h1>TAO Restaurant</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<div class="bottom">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>TAO Restaurant</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer to include your specific case. You can literally apply this to any element using any CSS property that can include an int value.

Comment: unfortunately, this solution consumes device's CPU , as CPU jumps up to 80%-90% while scrolling , so doing such thing with javascript won't be a good idea.